# How to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, uefi

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1, but I can't do the partitioning because Ubuntu does not recognize Windows 8.1. Everything was OK in Ubuntu, but when I shut down Ubuntu and booted to Windows, it looked like I had changed to "Zoom" because everything on the screen looked too big. I checked the appearance of the screen, and it was set at the default. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: For changing/fixing the zoom in the Windows 8.1 interface, I recommend asking somewhere like [Super User](http://superuser.com) where Windows is supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you have preinstalled Windows 8, your probably have a UEFI Bios system, in which case the safest way to install ubuntu in my opinion is to switch the UEFI to Legacy.

If you already attempted to install Windows 8 without the boot switch step, I would backup my data, repair or recover windows 8 then try install ubuntu after Legacy boot enabled.

If you insist on installing it using the UEFI Bios, you want to look at these steps:
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)